# Javascript Prototype changed but still accessing old methods

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype-chain

I was learning inheritance and Prototype chaining. I was stuck after seeing this behaviour of resetting the constructor function's prototype inside the function itself.
On instantiating

- Case

```js
const Person = function (name,age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
Person.prototype.calcAge = function () {
    console.log(`My age is ${2022-this.age}`);
}
const Student = function (name,age,course) {
    Person.call(this,name,age);
    this.course = course;
    Student.prototype = null; // This should set Student's Prototype to null and 
// thus should not let instance to access intro property.
}
Student.prototype.intro = function () {
    console.log(`I am ${this.name} and my course is ${this.course}`)
};


const mike = new Student("mike",2000,"cse");

mike.intro();
```

In the code above, the output is `I am mike and my course is cse` but while instantiating I did set `Student.prototype = null;` so how is mike instance still accessing intro method.

Comment: When your Student constructor is calling - new prototype has been already seted to new object (before first constructor line).
And it's very bad idea to change prototype every time when you call constructor, it shoudn't be ised like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment you call `new`, the prototype object is taken from `Student.prototype` and used to create `this`. So at that moment the proto of `this` is the object that `Student.prototype` references.

It is that proto reference that is later used to find the definition of `intro`. It is found via `Object.getPrototypeOf(mike)`, not via `Student.prototype`. The latter only serves for future constructions.

By setting `Student.prototype` to `null`, you only determine what will happen with the *next* use of `new Student`. But for the instance that was already created, it comes too late. `Object.getPrototypeOf(this)` (when in the constructor's execution), will still refer to the original prototype object.

Here some extra `console.log` to illustrate that point:

```js
const Person = function (name,age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
Person.prototype.calcAge = function () {
    console.log(`My age is ${2022-this.age}`);
}
const Student = function (name,age,course) {
    Person.call(this,name,age);
    this.course = course;
    // true:
    console.log(Student.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(this));

    Student.prototype = null; 
    // false:
    console.log(Student.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(this));
}

Student.prototype.intro = function () {
    console.log(`I am ${this.name} and my course is ${this.course}`)
};

const mike = new Student("mike",2000,"cse");
// true:
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(mike).hasOwnProperty("intro"));

mike.intro();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, That solved my doubt. Very clear Explanation!

Comment: sadly quicker than  my explanation, which I was well on with when this post appeared! But this deserves the tick, it's much clearer than mine! :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), the `new` operator does 4 things when used to call a function, of which the second is:

> Points newInstance's [[Prototype]] to the constructor function's prototype property.

And it adds the following note:

> Note: Properties/objects added to the constructor function's prototype property are therefore accessible to all instances created from the constructor function.

This is presumably known to you, and why you are expecting setting `Student.prototype` to `null` to stop any method calls on a `Student` instance from working.

But there is a big difference between:

1. "adding (functions) to the constructor function's prototype property" (which is what the above quote talks about, and what you do in setting `Student.prototype.intro` to a function), and
2. completely replacing the function's prototype property with a new value (in your case `null`)

When your example code runs, the above step involved in calling the `new` operator goes through as normal. Note that `Student.prototype` exists as soon as you declare the `Student` function - and it's (to all intents and purposes, anyway), an empty object. So the new Student instance - `mike` in your case - will be linked via the prototype chain to this object `Student.prototype`. Which contains an `intro` method because you added one explicitly (and you did so before instantiating the object).

When you set `Student.prototype` to `null`, later in the constructor, that doesn't change at all what `mike`'s prototype is (in the sense of the object that JS will look up property/method accesses on if you access a non-existent property, such as `intro`, on `mike`). That's still the same object it was before - an essentially empty one, with an `intro` method added. That object still exists, even though it's no longer accessible as `Student.prototype`. And it's still prototype-linked to `mike`, because that link already happened when you instantiated `mike`.

Of course, since `Student.prototype` is `null` after that first instantiation, things will go very wrong on the second one:

```js
const Person = function (name,age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
Person.prototype.calcAge = function () {
    console.log(`My age is ${2022-this.age}`);
}
const Student = function (name,age,course) {
    Person.call(this,name,age);
    this.course = course;
    Student.prototype = null; // This should set Student's Prototype to null and 
// thus should not let instance to access intro property.
}
Student.prototype.intro = function () {
    console.log(`I am ${this.name} and my course is ${this.course}`)
};


const mike = new Student("mike",2000,"cse");
const bob = new Student("bob", 1000, "math");
mike.intro();
bob.intro();
```

but (as still seen above), the first invocation is absolute fine.

If you absolutely need to remove one or more methods on the first instantiation (although why you want to do this, I cannot guess), then you need to mutate the `Student.prototype` reference rather than overwriting it. So replace

```
Student.prototype = null;
```

with

```
Student.prototype.intro = null;
```

(or similar)

Comment: Thanks @Robin for the elaborate explanation. It cleared my concepts.

Comment: Nice explanation as well, with references to documentation!